# Drawing an Arc in Tikz, WITHOUT Angles! (Only Two Points)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I'm curious how you can draw an arc in Tikz, with just an starting point and an ending point. A simple way to do it. No Bezier Curves, and nothing long, a simple command using `\draw`.

Right now I am trying:

```
\draw[dashed, thick, gray] (A) -- to[bend left] (B);
```

and I am getting the error "Cannot parse this coordinate"

Does any one have any better ideas?

Comment: Remove `--`, i.e., `\draw[dashed, thick, gray] (A) to[bend left] (B);`  After `--` (meaning 'draw a straight line'), TikZ expects a coordinate, but finds `to`, therefore the error message.

Comment: Absolute lifesaver. Thank you

Comment: Since an arc is not unambiguously defined by two points only (you need three points, else the radius of the arc isn't defined), `\draw (A) -- (B);` also fulfils the requirements as it is an arc between the two points with an infinite radius.

Comment: There is also \pgfpatharcto (page 1100).